# remove icon and drop-down from Edge browser Time input type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: Edge Time Selector]

I'm testing an App in Edge Chromium and have some time fields in a tight space. I'm attempting to remove the glyph/drop-down from the `<input type="time" />` field, but cannot find any way to hide/remove it.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

[Sample demo here](https://js-ortusn.stackblitz.io/).

Please open in Edge to see the icon.

thank you!

Comment: Providing sample code or a sample repository will help you find an answer quickly

Comment: I agree, but I'm not really sure how many details are needed?

Comment: you can add the raw HTML part or you can reproduce this using stackblitz.com

Comment: https://js-ortusn.stackblitz.io

Must be opened in Edge to see the icon. 
My issue is that I cannot even find the icon within a Devtool/ inspector so i'm not sure what the control would be called to find using css or javascript.

Comment: hi your repo in not opening, can you recheck the ulr

Comment: @CThin not sure of your requirements and project structure. may be just use `type=text` with javascript library to initialize timepicker on that input.

Comment: @CThin your demo site is not loading. May be try [codepen](https://codepen.io/)